# How to upload and process CSV File using ExtJS Client Side

Tags: javascript, extjs5, csv-import

I am trying to Upload a CSV File containing IP addresses using Ext-js and have it processed and converted into a JSON Object on the client-side before sending it to the server to be added to the repository.
I need to parse the CSV, convert it into a JSON Object and then add the information to a Data Store- but I'm terribly stuck.
Are there any existing libraries that can help achieve this?
I am looking at avoiding jQuery/HTML5. Is there a way we can do it exclusively using Javascript / Extjs?
I tried going through a lot of examples- but most of them use jQuery/HTML5 API/ Papa-Parse or prefer doing it server side.

My 'Upload' Button handler function looks like this:

```
handler: function () {
      var file = Ext.getCmp('form-file-win').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    var importedAddresses=[];
                   reader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                       importedAddresses=oFREvent.target.result;
                    };
                  reader.readAsText(file);
                    this.dataStore.add({
                       id: '',
                       name: 'Imported from CSV',
                   });
                    win.close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to access the content of the file on the client side.
You have two options:

1. You either post the file to the server and process it serves-side and give a json response for your javascript
2. Or you need to use HTML5 to access a local file. Here is a tutorial on how to do that: [local file processing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)